# Send user cart items via website contact form - without a plugin

Tags: cart, wpforms

I have website contact form that user submits after adding products to the cart. I want users to submit their cart items via this contact form. How do i add cart items in the form?

P.S I am using the free version of the WP Forms.

I did try some of the methods that are posted online but doesnt seem to have worked. I need something has worked for someone.